# Finding a pattern with optional end using regular expression

Tags: regex, match, string-matching

I am looking for **one single regular expression** to extract a block of text, which can be **surrounded with an optional end**. The challenge here is just to use a single regular expression.

The input is as follows:

```
Anchor:  This is the text I want to extract          A/C  : 2015-5-20
Anchor:  This is the text I want to extract
```

I am currently using the following regular expression

```
Anchor:(?<extact>.*)(A\/C)
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

If I make the A/C block optional, `Anchor:(?<extact>.*)(A\/C)?` using a `?` the matching gets to long:

It looks as follows:
[image]

Any ideas how to elegantly solve this with a single regex. An additional constraint is that I want to have a named block in the regex, (here `extact`)

You can find the sample code on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/wH5iQ4/1

Comment: Could you also post the exact matches you are looking for? I mean the preferred output. I am not sure that I fully understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Are the spaces before `A/C` consistent?

Comment: The spaces are not consistent before A/C but also not relevant. My intention is to extract everything from `Anchor:` to `A/C` or until the end of the line (including whitespaces)

Comment: Why not just use captured text 1? Look-arounds are always costlier in terms of performance. Use `Anchor:(?<extact>.*?)(\s*A\/C)` and just grab Group 1 text. Really, it is not a case when you *have to* use look-arounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Anchor:(?<extact>.*?)\s*(?=A\/C|$)
```

You can make use of `lookahead` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wH5iQ4/3

Comment: Slightly better: `Anchor:(?<extact>.*?)(?=\s*A\/C|\s*$)`

Comment: Any way I can avoid changing changing the sub-expression from ´(?<extact>.*)´ to `(?<extact>.*?)` ? In my application logic which generates the regex, this subexpression should remain static